# How to prove that a tychonoff space $C(X, Y)$ equipped with fine topology can be embedded in a tychonoff cube.

Tags: general-topology, function-spaces

As we know that a topological space is Tychonoff if and only if it can be embedded in a Tychonoff cube. We have that a function space $C(X, Y)$ equipped with fine topology where $X$ is a Tychonoff space and $Y$ also a (Tychonoff) metric space, is a Tychonoff space. How can we then prove that it can be embedded in a hilbert cube?

Comment: Is a Hilbert cube synonymous to a Tychonoff cube? For me any space of the form $[0,1]^I$ is called a Tychonoff cube. The Hilbert cube for me is the space $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ in particular (all in the product topology of course).

Comment: What’s the issue? If you already know $C(X,Y)$ is Tychonoff anyway (although it would be a good idea to add the definition for this topology to the question , as it’s not standard) then the *general* theorem you quoted already shows it can be embedded into a Tychonoff cube. No special stuff needed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I want to learn the proof of this, i mean how can we prove that general statement for this particular space.

Comment: You gain no new insight that way.  Just study the easy proof for general Tychonoff $X$ you don’t need that the Tychonoff space is really a function space (or anything really).

Answer (score 0):

If $Z$ is any Tychonoff space and its weight $w(Z)$ (the minimal (infinite) size of a base for $Z$) is $\kappa$ then $Z$ embeds into the Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^\kappa$ (and the weight of that cube is also $\kappa$). This can be applied to a space of the form $C(X,Y)$, when we know the topology on it is Tychonoff. It can *only* be embedded into the Hilbert cube if $w(C(X,Y)) = \aleph_0$ which will depend on the specific $X,Y$ of course.